# Missing reference error- VBA for Powerpoint 2011 on Mac (works fine in PPT 2007 for Windows)

Tags: macos, vba, powerpoint

Excited by the fact that VBA returned to Mac, but having trouble with code that works fine in Powerpoint 2007 for Windows (giving me a "Compile Error: User-defined type not defined" at the commented statement below):

```
Private Function m_CreateStackedChart(SourceData As Excel.Range) As Boolean

    Dim pptShape As PowerPoint.Shape
    Dim pptChart As PowerPoint.Chart ' // This line causes the error
    Dim pptSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim pptData As PowerPoint.ChartData
    Dim shtData As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim lngCol As Long
    Dim lngOutRow As Long
    Dim lngOutCol As Long
    Dim lngTopRow As Long
    Dim lngNItems As Long
    Dim dblXaxisSize As Double
    Dim lngAxisFactor As Long
    Dim strHolderName As String
    Dim rngXData As Range
    Dim rngYData As Range
    Dim lngNRows As Long
    Dim lngSeries As Long
    Dim objDLabel As Object
    Dim strFormat As String
    ....
End Function
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll be able to do much with charts in Mac PPT 2011, at least not as it stands as of July 2011 (after applying the first service pack).

The .Chart object isn't revealed in the PowerPoint 2011 object model.  PowerPoint's VBA implementation and OM seem to be at about the stage things were at in Office 2007 before the first service pack for it came out.

Answer (score 0):

I've just stumbled across this thread and whilst it's disappointing news, I just checked PowerPoint:mac 2016 and the Chart object model appears to be pretty well implemented in that product.